Is there a HashMap that can store multiple values per key while minimizing allocations?
I need a data structure in Rust that can store multiple values per key.
The data structure should have the following operations:

add a new value to a key
iterate over every value for a key and remove them

It should not be necessary to allocate new memory every time a new key is added.
I expect that there will be mostly only one value per key, but that could change in the future.
I considered using HashMap<Key, Vec> but then I would have to create a new Vec every time a new key is added, that would result in a memory allocation.
I found the crate multimap, but that seems to be just a wrapper for HashMap<Key, Vec>.
I could use something like Vec<(Key, Value)> but the performance for iterating and removing values for a key wouldn't be optimal.

Without really knowing Rust, I don't understand how you expect a non-fixed-size container to avoid allocations when you add elements to it.

@DavidW OP says "to allocate new memory every time a new key is added", so I guess he means he wants something that only re-allocates noce capacity is reached to obtain amortized O(1) time insertions?

Are you trying to avoid heap-allocating the value when the key is unique, which you say is the common case? You could use a crate like smallvec, tinyvec, etc., that stores small vectors inline without indirection.

You can certainly avoid allocating when there is only a single value with a crate like smallvec or with an Either<Value, Vec<Value>>, but this smells of premature optimization. I would simply go for a HashMap<Key, Vec<Value>> until and unless benchmarking shows that this is the performance bottleneck.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your requirement can be boiled down to:

What is a collection which avoids memory allocations for few items, but otherwise allows an unbounded amount of items?

And the simplest collection which meets this requirement is SmallVec. A SmallVec<[T; N]> will:

Store between 0 and isize::MAX elements of type T.
Store said elements inline if there's less than (or equal to) N of them.
And otherwise save the elements on the heap.

It does come with overhead, specifically one usize worth of overhead, which is used to:

Store the length (up to isize::MAX),
Store a single-bit tag indicating whether the elements are stored inline or on the heap.

It also has a minimum size of 3 usize, so you'll want to pick [T; N] to be close to at least 2 usize of memory... which will be the case even for [T; 1] in most cases. For example [String; 1] is already bigger than that.
With SmallVec under your belt, then you can just use: HashMap<K, SmallVec<[V; 1]>> and be done with it.
It's just like HashMap<K, Vec<V>>, minus the memory allocations whenever there's a single element.

Maybe you can use the following approach:

Keep the main map (as HashMap) that contains your first key-value pairs and an additional optional index that points to the next value with the same key if it exists (else None). So the type of the map should be HashMap<K, (T, Option<usize>)>, where K is the key type, T is the stored data type.
Keep the extra values (with duplicated keys) in an additional vector that contains tuples of the stored values and indices to the next values in the vector with the same key. So the type of the vector should be Vec<(T, Option<usize>)>. This way you store all duplicated values with different keys in the same vector.

Since as you mentioned normally you have only one value for each key, the additional vector should not have a big size, so with respect to the performance mainly you can work with the structure as a plain hashmap with a small overhead for checking the next index.
I also attached a working code that supports inserting into the structure and iterating. I hope, this will make your issue clearer.
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::iter::from_fn;
use std::collections::HashMap;


#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct MyStruct<K, T> {
    map: HashMap<K, (T, Option<usize>)>,  // Basic value and reference (index) to additional values
    extra: Vec<(T, Option<usize>)>,  // Additional values with indices to next ones
}


impl<K: Eq + Hash, T> MyStruct<K, T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            map: HashMap::new(),
            extra: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, key: K, val: T) {
        // Check the key in the map
        match self.map.get_mut(&key) {
            Some(item) => {
                // Add value to `extra`
                let idx = self.extra.len();
                self.extra.push((val, None));

                // Update the next indices
                let mut nx: &mut Option<usize> = &mut item.1;
                while let Some(loc) = *nx {
                    nx = &mut self.extra[loc].1;
                }
                *nx = Some(idx);
            },
            None => {
                // Add value to the map normally
                self.map.insert(key, (val, None));
            },
        }
    }

    pub fn iter(&self, key: K) -> impl Iterator<Item = &T> {
        // Get item from the map
        let mut next = self.map.get(&key);

        // Follow next returning the value
        from_fn(move || next.map(|item| {
            next = item.1.map(|loc| &self.extra[loc]);
            &item.0
        }))
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut ms = MyStruct::<&str, i64>::new();
    ms.insert("key1", 25);
    ms.insert("key2", 32);
    ms.insert("key3", 55);
    ms.insert("key1", 12);
    ms.insert("key1", 101);
    ms.insert("key2", 3);
    println!("{:?}", ms);
    println!("{:?}", ms.iter("key2").collect::<Vec<&i64>>());
}


Looks horrible if you want to remove elements, which is something OP mentioned.

@kmdreko Maybe I would agree, but it depends on the way OP wants to remove: all the elements by key, or by key-value pair, or by the index. Final usage matters. I just suggested a possible way to manage the data. Of course, any data structure has disadvantages in some cases, so this is why we have many of them instead of "the best" one for any situation.
